# Plugin, add opengraph tags after form submit

Tags: plugins, open-graph

Im developing plugin which calculates child date of birth and so on. So what I need is to add opengraph tags with appropriate data when someone wants to share the page on facebook. What i want is that these tags are appended to head only if someone had actually pressed submit button on the form.

When I do it like this:

```
if($_GET['calc_submit_1']) {
   function add_open_graph_tags(){    
   echo '<meta property="og:url" content="'.$shortlink.'" />';
   echo '<meta property="og:title" content="Ich bin in der '.floor($week_of_pregnancy).'. Schwangerschaftswoche" />';
   echo '<meta property="og:description" content="Ich habe den myToys-Fruchtbarkeitsrechner benutzt und folgendes Ergebnis erhalten: '.$shortlink.'" />';
   echo '<meta property="og:image" content="http://mytoys.beta-preview.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/wallhaven-411.jpg" />';
  }     
  add_action('wp_head', 'add_open_graph_tags');
}
```

The tags are not added to wp_head hook. Is it possible to do it the way i want? Any help appreciated.

Comment: I guess you are executing that code in the wrong place. Can you provide the context/file where that code is executed?

Answer (score 0):

Your function will only be called when there is something in`$_GET['calc_submit_1']`. Means, when you submit the form, your function is triggered. When you refresh the page, and `$_GET['calc_submit_1']` is empty, it won't triggered. When FB checks for OG, FB will not submit your form and your function will not be triggered. 
You can use `add_option` to save something in to database on form submit, and check that, instead of `$_GET['calc_submit_1']`.

Comment: You are totallly right, but I think that the OP wants to generate a dinamic URL from the form (URL + query string generated by the form, note it is submitted with get method), so each user can share exactly what they have set in the form, I guess, it is not described in the quesiton.

Comment: @cybmeta you are right. He should describe his scenario. If it's a dynamic URL, and his query string is available in the URL, then it should work.

Comment: Yeah thats what i really want. After user submits form it gets the results (parameters in the url by get). And then social share icons appears - so the user should share exactly results with specific text (opengraph tags). Strange thing its not added to head as i wrote at start...

Comment: @kroma where did you put your codes?

Comment: @тнє Sufi function calculator_1($atts) {
here i render calculator

if($_GET['calc_submit_1']) {
things from my first post
}

}

Comment: Well, I was asking, in which file did you put your codes?

Comment: In my plugin file. Doesnt matter now. Found the answer - thing is you cannot hook into wp_head from shortcode. Didnt mention that my bad. My plugin was adding shortcode to generate calculator wherever I want (post, page)

Comment: In that case, you are right. You need to hook `wp_head` before `get_header` to make it work.